# CoordinatorLayout with RecyclerView in different fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a Fragment with a CoordinatorLayout and FrameLayout to fill with other Fragments. One of these Fragment contains one RecyclerView. My question is, how RecyclerView can work with CoordinatorLayout each of which is in a file. I tried to put a NestedScrollView as Fragment parent, but when I do this "onBindViewHolder" of the adapter RecyclerView is called for all elements.

Main Fragment contains the CoordinatorLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorTab"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_restaurant"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment with RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/background"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This way the scroll works, but the "onBindViewHolder" is called for all listed items, including those who are not "visible". If I put a LinearLayout instead of NestedScrollView, the "onBindViewHolder" works the right way but the scroll behavior ("@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior") with CoordinatorLayout does not work.

Comment: If you use `NestedScrollView` to wrap `RecyclerView`. Recycle function won't work. And it will use more memory and lags.

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollView` draws all it's child elements. Which means your `Recyclerview` loses it's recycling properties when it's inside a `Scrollview`. That is why `onBindViewHolder` is called for all items.  Also it is incorrect behaviour.

Try keeping parent as `FrameLayout` with scroll behavior ("@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior")

Comment: I understand, but change NestedScrollView by FrameLayout not work for scrolling behavior. It works if FrameLayout is in the same file that CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: Try changing height of your FrameLayout(which is present inside coordinatorlayout) to `match_parent`.

Comment: Did not work. I think the problem is the NestedScrollView whenever I use it all the items are loaded into onBindViewHolder . I tried to set the height of NestedScrollView did not work. There is another layout I could use instead of NestedScrollView and has a scrolling behavior?

Comment: I had faced a similar issue and was able to get scrolling behaviour through `RelativeLayout`/`FrameLayout`. You can try `RelativeLayout` as parent of fragment but i doubt the problem is somewhere else.